# How to pass data to the View Controller using asynchronous NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, asynchronous

I have View Controller where I get data from web, parse Json, and pass string to another View Controller. If I use synchronous `NSURLConnection`, everything works just fine.

But if I switch to the asynchronous, then method `(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)` calls before parsing Json data which I got from web.

Just jump over `_jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil]` method. Any thoughts? Thank you in advance for your help. Here is my code:

```
-(void)getClothInfo {
    NSString *allowedClothSizeToServer = [_foreignSizeToServer     stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSString *getDataURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xsdcompany.com/jsoncloth.php?foreignSize=%@",allowedClothSizeToServer];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

        if (connectionError) {
            [self showAlertWithMessage2:@"Server is Unavialable"];
        } else {
            _jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

            //Loop trough our jsonArray
            for (int i=0; i<_jsonArray.count; i++) {
                //Create our size object
                _usSizeFromServer = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"usSizeCloth"];
            }
        }
    }];
}

- (IBAction)getIt:(id)sender {
    // Validate data
    if ([self validData] == NO)
    {
         return;
    }

    [self getClothInfo];
    [self showNextViewController];
}

-(void) showNextViewController {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GetCLothInfo" sender:nil];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ResultViewController *resultViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    resultViewController.foreignSizeToResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ size for %@ is %@", [_pickerProcessor selectedCountry].countryName, [_pickerProcessor selectedCloth].clothName, [_pickerProcessor selectedSize].sizeName];
    resultViewController.dataForUsSize = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your US size for %@ is %@", [_pickerProcessor selectedCloth].clothName, _usSizeFromServer];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. You could call `showNextViewController` from the completion block inside the `getClothInfo` method. Or better, add a completion block parameter to your `getClothInfo` method and call that from the completion block for the `NSURLConnection`.

Something like this:

```
-(void)getClothInfo:(void ^(void))completion {
    NSString *allowedClothSizeToServer = [_foreignSizeToServer     stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSString *getDataURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xsdcompany.com/jsoncloth.php?foreignSize=%@",allowedClothSizeToServer];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

        if (connectionError) {
            [self showAlertWithMessage2:@"Server is Unavialable"];
        } else {
            _jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

            //Loop trough our jsonArray
            for (int i=0; i<_jsonArray.count; i++) {
                //Create our size object
                _usSizeFromServer = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"usSizeCloth"];
            }

            if (completion) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     completion();
                });
            }
        }
    }];
}

- (IBAction)getIt:(id)sender {
    // Validate data
    if ([self validData] == NO)
    {
         return;
    }

    [self getClothInfo:^ {
        [self showNextViewController];
    }];
}
```

Comment: The code I posted may have a typo or two. It wasn't tested but should give you a good start.

Comment: First approach works, thank you! Second gave me two errors: 1) '-(void)getClothInfo:(void ^(void))completion' - Block pointer to non-function type is invalid 2) 'if (completion) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    completion();' - Called object type id is not a function pointer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want your json data to be downloaded before you segue, in that case the synchronous NSURLConnection makes sense

When you make an asynchronous NSURLConnection call, it means that the subsequent code will be executed ( in this case the performSegue).

It would help if you could explain what your expected behavior is

Comment: You're right, I need get data, parse it, and assign it to the string BEFORE to show next View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Register for notification when response is obtained from the connection using

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ResponseObtained" object:_jsonArray];
```

in the second view controller add observer for notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleResponse:)
                                             name:@"ResponseObtained"
                                           object:nil];
```

You can access _jasonArray in handleResponse method with

```
- (void)handleResponse:(NSNotification *)notif{

    NSDictionary *result = [notif object]; }
```